# Можете помочь не понимаю почему в условии if дальше первого or скрипт не учитывает

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
month = str(input('Введите месяц в году (с маленькой буквы)'))
if month == ('январь' or 'март' or 'май' or 'июль' or 'август' or 'октябрь' or 'декабрь'):
  print('в этом месяце 31 день')
elif month == ('февраль'):
  print('в этом месяце может быть как 28 так и 29 дней')
elif month == ('апрель' or 'июнь' or 'сентябрь' or 'ноябрь'):
  print('в этом месяце 30 дней')
```

Comment: Как думаете какое значение у выражения `'январь' or 'март'` ?

Comment: В вашем случае лучше писать так.
if month in ('январь', 'март', и т.д)

Answer (score 2):

Если есть список значений, используйте `in` -- это более короткий вариант проверки, чем писать множество условий, объединённых `or`

Также не забудьте указать ошибку при некорректном вводе.

```py
month = str(input('Введите месяц в году (с маленькой буквы)'))
if month in ['январь', 'март', 'май', 'июль', 'август', 'октябрь', 'декабрь']:
    print('в этом месяце 31 день')
elif month == 'февраль':
    print('в этом месяце может быть как 28 так и 29 дней')
elif month in ['апрель', 'июнь', 'сентябрь', 'ноябрь']:
    print('в этом месяце 30 дней')
else:
    print('месяц неизвестен:', month)
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение для вашего кода. Но это как-то неправильно

```py
month = str(input('Введите месяц в году (с маленькой буквы)'))
if month == 'январь' or month == 'март' or month == 'май' or month == 'июль' or month == 'август' or month == 'октябрь' or month == 'декабрь':
  print('в этом месяце 31 день')
elif month == 'февраль':
  print('в этом месяце может быть как 28 так и 29 дней')
elif month == 'апрель' or month == 'июнь' or month == 'сентябрь' or month == 'ноябрь':
  print('в этом месяце 30 дней')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import calendar

cal=calendar.LocaleTextCalendar(firstweekday=0, locale="ru")
year,month=map(int,input("Введите год и номер месяца (типа 2023 9)  ").split())
cal.prmonth(year,month)
```